# Ebooks that allow handwritten notes

Tags: ebook-readers, annotations, apps, website

Is there a place to buy ebooks that allow handwritten notes in the apps used to read them? I'm considering buying etextbooks, and want to be able to write handwritten notes in them with a wacom pad. But I haven't seen ebook sellers and apps that allow that. I'm talking about apps, not special ereaders.